# extract all data from struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab

After using the load function to read a struct I created earlier into a new struct called x (for example), I get a struct with the dimensions 1X1. this struct, x, contains the struct I'm interested in. how can I extract the inner struct without using the field name?

Comment: why do you want  "extract the inner struct without using the field name"?

Comment: Imagine yo have a struct that contains a struct inside it. I want to extract the inner struct. I hope this time is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

Let's suppose you have created the following example struture:

```
original_struct.var_field_1=123
original_struct.var_field_2=333
original_struct.var_field_3='this is the original struct'
```

and that, then, you've saved it in a `.mat` file called `saved_original_struct`

```
save('saved_original_struct','original_struct')
```

- if you know / remember the name of the original struct saved in the `.mat` file, you can simply call `load` without specifying the output variable and the struct with its original name (`original_struct`) will be available in the WorkSpace and you can work with it.

Implementation:

```
load('saved_original_struct')

whos original_struct
   Name                 Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
   original_struct      1x1               442  struct
```

- if you do not know / remember the name of the original struct, you can call `load` specifying the output variable

The returned variable is a struct, so you can use:

- `fieldnames` to get the name of the field of in the loaded struct (that is the name of your original structure)
- `getfield` to extract your original structure from the one loaded

Implementation:

```
loaded_struct=load('saved_original_struct')
str_name=char(fieldnames(loaded_struct))
extracted_struct=getfield(loaded_struct,str_name)


extracted_struct = 

   var_field_1: 123
   var_field_2: 333
   var_field_3: 'this is the original struct'
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'